# My clear all channels command doesn't seem to work. (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created a discord bot, and I wanted a clear all channels command, basically `.clear`
I had zero issues with other commands + no other clear command. However when I use `.help`, it doesn't show the clear command & it doesn't work.
Oh yeah, the error I'm getting is "Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "clear" is not found"
my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from discord import Permissions
from colorama import Fore, Style
import asyncio
#imports for reference

@client.command
@commands.is_owner()
 async def clear(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    guild = ctx.guild
    for channel in guild.channels:
     try:
      await channel.delete()
      print (Fore.GREEN + f"{channel.name} was deleted" + Fore.RESET)
     except:
        print (Fore.RED + f"{channel.name} was not deleted" + Fore.RESET)
        return


#I fixed it, what I had to do was instead of @client.command I was meant to put @client.command()
```